# Recursive-ish query for tags?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a table of tags that can be linked to other tags and I want to "recursively" select the tags in order of arrangement. So that when a search is made, we get the immediate (1-level) results and then carry on down to say 5-levels so that we always have a list of tags no matter if there wasn't enough exact matches on level 1.

I can manage this fine with making multiple queries until I get enough results, but surely there is a better, optimized, way via a one-trip query?

Any tips will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Results:

```
tagId, tagWord, child, child tagId
'513', 'Slap', 'Hog Slapper', '1518'
'513', 'Slap', 'Corporal Punishment', '147'
'513', 'Slap', 'Impact Play', '1394'
```

Query:

```
SELECT t.tagId, t.tagWord as tag, tt.tagWord as child, tt.tagId as childId

FROM platform.tagWords t

INNER JOIN platform.tagsLinks l ON l.parentId = t.tagId
INNER JOIN platform.tagWords tt ON tt.tagId = l.tagId

WHERE t.tagWord = 'slap'
```

Table Layouts:

```
mysql> explain tagWords;
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| tagId   | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| tagWord | varchar(45)         | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain tagsLinks;
+----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| tagId    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| parentId | bigint(20)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Mysql doesn't have any mechanism for querying data recursively

Oracle has `Connected By` construct and Sql Server has `CTE(Common Table Expressions)`.

But Mysql, 
Read [Here](http://www.aota.net/forums/showthread.php?t=19747) and [Here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=26251)

Comment: Just to complete the list: Firebird, PostgreSQL and DB2 support recursive queries as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the options that I consider each time I find myself in a situation when I need to **query** hierarchical data.

1. [Nested Sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)
2. [Path enumeration](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2004/08/05/hierarchical_sql.html)
3. Explicit joins (when the maximum level is known)
4. Vendor Extensions ([SQL Server CTE](http://blog.crowe.co.nz/blog/archive/2007/09/06/Microsoft-SQL-Server-2005---CTE-Example-of-a-simple.aspx), [Oracle Connect by](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries003.htm) etc)
5. Stored Procedures
6. [Suck it up](http://lolcatz.net/view.asp?id=39b669b9-0b87-4557-9079-041b4caa1e59&t=&tid=1&p=1&pid=2&irp=8)